# Rod partitioning in n pieces

Tags: calculus, inequality

A straight rod of length n units (obviously n is an integer) is to be partitioned into n pieces of random length. All pieces are to be used to form triangular constructions, so we are looking for the boundaries for the length of the largest piece, to ensure that this will be possible with any 3.

If the largest piece is $n_i$ units long, and its largest and smallest possible lengths are $x_i$ and $y_i$, then $y_i \leq n_i \leq x_i$ and then for all other pieces, it will be:
$n_j \leq y_i$.

Also $\sum n_i \leq \sum y_i = n*y_i$.

Therefore for any 3 pieces, we will have:

$y_i \leq y_1 \leq n_1 \leq x_1 \leq x_i$ and same for $n_2$ and $n_3$.
Wlg we consider $n_1 \leq n_2 \leq n_3$.

In order for the 3 pieces to form a triangle, it must be $n_1+n_2 \leq n_3$, $n_1+n_3 \leq n_2$ and $n_2+n_3 \leq n_1$. Also $n_3-n_2 \geq n_1$, $n_2-n_1 \geq n_3$ and $n_3-n_1 \geq n_2$.

An obvious solution would be to have all segments equal to 1 unit, so we could form $\frac {n}{3}$ equilateral triangles but obviously this is not the general case.

I have seen several solutions to similar problems but with very advanced math (integrals etc) and I can't follow the solutions.

I wonder if there is any solution with basic calculus (11th or 12th grade) because I don't have any maths background. FYI this is not homework or assignment.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do the lengths have to be integer?

Comment: @RaahithyaVemulakonda, no, only n is an integer. I will edit my post.

Comment: For $n \gt 3$ no length can guarantee that a triangle can be formed with any three pieces.  Given any length, there could be two pieces each less than half that long.  For $n=3$ if the largest is less than $1.5$ the other two will add up to more than that and a triangle can be made, so the range is $[1,1.5)$

Comment: It is unclear what $n_i$, $x_i$, $y_i$ mean. When "the largest piece is $n_i$ units long" you cannot sum over $i$ later on. What do you mean by "random length"?

Comment: In order for the 3 pieces of lengths $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_3$ to form a triangle, it must be 
$n_1+n_2 \ge n_3$, $n_1+n_3 \ge n_2$ and $n_2+n_3 \ge n_1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter let's say that the rod is 1000 units long and we cut it into 1000 smaller pieces of random lengths. We want to find the boundaries (upper - lower length) for the largest piece (therefore all others will be smaller than this one) so that we can form a triangle with any 3 of all pieces.

Comment: So maybe the answer is that the range for the largest piece is [1,1]? In which case, all other pieces must also be in the same range, because if there were a smaller piece, then, in order for all n pieces to add up to a total length of n, there should also be a larger one, which is a contradiction, since the largest is in [1,1]. Does this hold?

Comment: @WangXiuYingZhang it makes some sense to me but I can't prove it. Let's wait to see if anyone posts a nice solution!

Comment: @RossMillikan happy new year. So you agree that the only valid solution is $[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$?

Comment: For $n \gt 3$ I agree.  For $n=3$ it is $[1,1.5)$ because if the longest is less than $1.5$ the other two will sum to more than its length.

Comment: So the read of this question is "Longest length $l$ such that no matter how the rest is cut up, we can always form a triangle with the remaining pieces"? That seems like a weird question to ask since it renders the $ n > 4$ cases trivial. My initial interpretation is "Longest length $l$ such that there exists a way to cut up the pieces allowing us to form a triangle".

Answer (score 1):

$n\geq 3$ and let $l$ be the longest rod piece length, then $l\geq 1$ otherwise we would have $n$ pieces of lengths less than $1$ and so the total sum less than $<n$ contradicting that the sum is $=n$, so $1$ is the lower bound for $l$ and we want to find the upper bound of the interval for values for the longest length, if $l$ the maximum length then $ \frac{n-l}{n-1}$ is the average length of the remaining $n-1$ pieces and so there must be a pair such that there combined length is $ \leq 2 \frac{n-l}{n-1}$ otherwise all pairs lengths are bigger $ > 2\frac{n-l}{n-1}$ which means that the sum of all lengths is bigger than $>n$ which is contradiction and so we need that $2 \frac{n-l}{n-1} \geq l $ which means that $ 2n \geq (n+1)l $ and so $l \leq \frac{2n}{n+1}$ and so the interval of the longest rod piece is $[1,\frac{2n}{n+1}]$.

Comment: Remember that the condition is to be able to make a triangle with any 3 of the pieces; so if, say, n=4, then the longest is between 1 and $\frac {8}{5}$ and the remaining 3 must have a total length of $\frac {12}{5}$. Say for example that the 3 pieces are $\frac {3}{5}, \frac {3}{5}, \frac {6}{5}$. Then with $\frac {3}{5}, \frac {3}{5}, \frac {8}{5}$ we can't make a triangle.

Comment: you are right but this $\frac{4}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{8}{5}$ works, what i proved is that for any value in the interval $[1,\frac{2n}{n+1}]$ you will always find a valid values for all lengths but for $<1$ or bigger than $>\frac{8}{5}$ you can't find a valid values.

Comment: try this for $\frac{8}{5}+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ and you will fail to produce a valid values for pieces lengths.

Comment: I still believe that the only valid solution is that all pieces are of the same length and equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ and, of course, so is the largest.

Comment: @Ahmad I agree with your interpretation of the phrasing.